# How to add a String to another String array in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

This my java code, here i have to add a string "RFID" in a String Array itemtypes and i have to stored it in an another string array item.But im getting an error.

```
  String[] itemtype;
  String[] item;
     \...........
      .........../
   try {
                response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                Koradcnos = response.toString();
            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            itemtypes = Koradcnos.split(";");
            item=itemtypes+"RFID";//here im getting error
        } catch (Exception er) {
            //Helper.warning("Error", er.toString(),this);
        }
         imageId = new int[itemtypes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < itemtypes.length; i++)
            if (itemtypes[i].equals("Yarn")) {
                imageId[i] = R.drawable.yarnitem;
```

Comment: item is of the type `String array`, you cannot concatenate a `String` to it. You might want to use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: `item[index] = itemtypes+"RFID";` should do the trick ;)

Comment: Still Im getting an error at index! What should i do now? How to rectify it ??Please give me a solution for this@shark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work around for this :

Using with `Arrays.copyOf`

```
item =  Arrays.copyOf(itemtypes , itemtypes.length + 1);
item[item.length - 1] = "RFID";
```

Or direct split from `Koradcnos`

```
item = (Koradcnos + ";RFID").split(";");
```

Answer (score 0):

`itemtypes` is String array,it can't be modified,if you want to get a new array adding another element,you can use [System.arrayCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

```
System.arraycopy(Object src,  
             int  srcPos,
             Object dest, 
             int destPos,
             int length)
```

Like this:

```
item = new String[itemtypes.length+1];
System.arraycopy(itemtypes,0,item,0,itemtypes.length);
item[itemtypes.length] = "RFID";
```

Comment: It's showing an error(method call expected) at itemtypes.length()+1 in the above code.

Comment: @prabhu,length is property,not method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate string with a list `String.split()` method returns a String array.

Instead of `item=itemtypes+"RFID"` iterate through the array as:

```
for (int i=0; i < itemtypes.length();  i++) {
    item[i] = itemtypes[i] + "RFID";
}
```

Also I think the variable name will be `itemtypes` instead of `itemtype`